# How to verify auction payments?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am planning on making a React Native app that would feature a **realtime auction** with users bidding (using Firebase). After an auction is won, the user would theoretically receive the product instantly.

Does anyone know how I can ensure that each user who is trying to place a bid will actually be able to pay the final cost of the item if they are to win? I don't think a $1 credit card charge will be enough to verify that the buyer will be able to pay for an expensive item. For example, if there is an auction for something that is over $1000, how can I verify that each user who places a bid will actually pay for the item if they win?

Also, if anyone knows of any preexisting packages or software to create an auction that could be embedded into a React Native app, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: There is no library only solution for this.  This is an entire application unto itself with lots of legal ramifications.  Plainly, this is too broad a question for this site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project. instead of credit card verification, I used an internal wallet for down payment deposit so the user has to pay a refundable deposit to activate his ability to participate in the auctions.

the user who won the auction has to pay the product cost within a period of time, otherwise he will lose his deposited amount and his user will be deactivated from making any bidding till he make a new deposit payment. And so on.